# Session lost with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I manage to log in with passport.js

```
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
        res.cookie('username', req.user.username);
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

but after that my session seems lost.

```
    app.post('/user/favorites', function(req, res) {
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.

    console.log(req.user); // Undefined
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) { // false
        console.log('HI');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the user cookie manually, let passport do it for you

```
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
  if (err) { return next(err); }
  return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
});
```

replace your cookie line with this.

Source:http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/ (see custom callback section)

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions given in documentation, try(if not already done)

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```